# How can I convert JSON format file to JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I use a dojo request.get to read a txt file in JSON format, but can't convert it to JSON object.
The "datagrid.txt" stored some data as:

```
[
{"col1":"val1", "col2":"val2", "col3":"val3"},
{"col1":"val1", "col2":"val2", "col3":"val3"},
{"col1":"val1", "col2":"val2", "col3":"val3"}
]
```

The requesting client code is as:

```
require(['dojo/_base/lang', 'dojox/grid/DataGrid', 'dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/request', 'dojo/domReady!'],
function(lang, DataGrid, ItemFileWriteStore, dom, request){ 

request.get("datagrid.txt",{
       // Parse data from JSON to a JavaScript object
        handleAs: "json"
    }
).then(
    function(text){          
        var datalist = JSON.stringify(text);            
        for(var i = 0, l = 16; i < l; i++){
            console.log( datalist[i] );             
        }
            });
```

The console.log displays things in string(such as "[","{"), not what as I expected an array({"col1":"val1", "col2":"val2", "col3":"val3"}), which I could used to populate a dojo datagrid data store.

Comment: Replace `JSON.stringify(text)` with `JSON.parse(text)`.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo can handle the JSON format on its own. [Official docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/json.html#dojo-json-parse)

Answer (score 0):

I think your Problem lies in the way you're writing your datagrid.txt and the style you try to read the data later.

Here's my solution:

```
require(['dojo/_base/lang', 'dojox/grid/DataGrid', 'dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore',
'dojo/dom', 'dojo/request', 'dojo/domReady!'],

function(lang, DataGrid, ItemFileWriteStore, dom, request){ 
request.get("datagrid.txt",{
   // Parse data from JSON to a JavaScript object
    handleAs: "json"
}
).then(
function(text){          
    var datalist = [];
     dojo.forEach(text,function(thisText,i){
     //add each single Object from the datagrid.txt to datagrid-array
     datalist.push(thisText);  
     //alert the newly added item in datagrid
     console.log(datalist);             
      });
   });
```

I think this should fix your Problem.
Regards, Miriam

Comment: Question: Does "identifier", "label", "items" inherent keywords for Javascript/Dojo to understand? Why they should be there?

Comment: Hi there! You can write it the way you do, or when you want to use it for an ITemFileReadStor further, do it like i do. identifier, label and items are therefore necessary: You can read more here:http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/simple.html?highlight=json#id1 - Try to get the cosole.log(datalist) just with datalist.

Comment: OK, now I understand the ITemFileReadStore expected data format. In fact, for the first time I use your code, it worked to show the data on a Dojo datagrid. I changed the datagrid.txt manually. As the datagrid.txt is also generated by another perl script, I changed the script to generate the correct datagrid.txt, but the Dojo datagrid didn't work correctly any more and I got "Unexpected token i" error which I didn't get for the first time. Does the "i" also a dojo-known loop iterator which needn't a declaration?

Comment: I suspect the error may due to the perl generated datagrid.txt. However I compared with your data and didn't find any important difference. I'll check again.

Comment: I included all keys in quotation marks and the error disappears. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Could you help to have a look on this post? stackoverflow.com/questions/19970321/how-to-set-color-to-cell-of-data-grid-in-dojo-dynamically